# getting wrong output when adding to array ruby on rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, include

```
experience_values = ["expert"]
@listing_data = 
{
          :image_url => "/images/original/missing.png",
          :expertise => "Expert",
             :skills => [
            [0] "Default category"
        ],
                 :id => "d8nVaHWz2oP4ki8ayT9Nog",
         :given_name => "Ritik",
        :family_name => "Som",
        :work_domain => "it ",
          :languages => "english",
        :description => "engineer",
           :location => ""
    },
    [1] {
          :image_url => "/images/original/missing.png",
          :expertise => "Beginner",
             :skills => [
            [0] "Default category"
        ],
                 :id => "mkfVPmAWHbMG6MT8rp_KKw",
         :given_name => "Ritik",
        :family_name => "Som",
        :work_domain => "",
          :languages => "",
        :description => "",
           :location => ""
    }



ll = []
            @listing_data.each do |lal|
                experience_values.each do |ee|
                    # binding.pry
                    if lal[:expertise].include? ee
                        ll.push(@listing_data)
                    end
                end
            end
            ll = ll.uniqll = []
            @listing_data.each do |lal|
                experience_values.each do |ee|
                    # binding.pry
                    if lal[:expertise].include? ee
                        ll.push(@listing_data)
                    end
                end
            end
            ll = ll.uniq
```

When I am doing the above code its adding both the element if ll array but only first one contains expert.Someone please help.I am stuck and not able to move ahead.I am working on ruby on rails for quite often.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code

looks like listing_data is array of hash

```
experience_values = ["expert"]

listing_data = [{
  :image_url => "/images/original/missing.png",
  :expertise => "Expert",
  :skills => ["Default category"],
  :id => "d8nVaHWz2oP4ki8ayT9Nog",
  :given_name => "Ritik",
  :family_name => "Som",
  :work_domain => "it ",
  :languages => "english",
  :description => "engineer",
  :location => ""
},{
  :image_url => "/images/original/missing.png",
  :expertise => "Beginner",
  :skills => ["Default category"],
  :id => "mkfVPmAWHbMG6MT8rp_KKw",
  :given_name => "Ritik",
  :family_name => "Som",
  :work_domain => "",
  :languages => "",
  :description => "",
  :location => ""
}]

listing_data.select {|h| experience_values.include? h[:expertise].downcase }
```

out put

```
[{:image_url=>"/images/original/missing.png", :expertise=>"Expert", :skills=>["Default category"], :id=>"d8nVaHWz2oP4ki8ayT9Nog", :given_name=>"Ritik", :family_name=>"Som", :work_domain=>"it ", :languages=>"english", :description=>"engineer", :location=>""}]
```